# Does java.util.Properties support nested properties?

Tags: java, nested, properties-file

I'm trying to set up environment-specific properties in a file, customized for each device running the code. I'd like to be able to nest some properties in others, for example:

```
browser=chrome
baseUrl=${server}/app/login.do
server=http://localhost
```

I'd like to be able to get `http://localhost/app/login.do` when I get the `baseUrl` property.

Does `java.util.Properties` support this behavior? If not, is there another core class that does?

Comment: You can use Apache Configuration to do this, but no in built class, unless you write it yourself.

Comment: No. Easy enough to test, and probably quicker and certainly more reliable than asking here.

Comment: @EJP Testing `Properties`'s *default* behavior is easy, but there may be options to alter the behavior a bit, thus asking. I also asked if there is another core class that *does* provide this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is No. java.util.Properties operates on Strings only.

> Each key and its corresponding value in the property list is a string.
>   (From Javadoc)

Edit:
No core Java class does that, as no core Java framework/class is designed to do such a thing.
I like [Typesafe's Config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

Comment: That answers the first part of my question, but doesn't look at other core classes that could fill the need.